# how to apply javascript function only to the element that is hovered

Tags: javascript

I selected two elements with same class with `document.querySelectorAll` and i want to apply function `onmousemove` but only to the element which has mousemove. Problem is that i dont know how to make it work on both elements but only when that element is hovered (onmousemove over it). I tried this

```
let menuSingle = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__single');
let menuSingleText = document.querySelector('.navigation__single-text');

menuSingle.onmousemove = function (e) {
    callParallax(e);
};

menuSingle.onmouseleave = function (e) {
    TweenMax.to(menuSingleText, 2, {
        y: 0,
        ease: Power3.easeOut
    });
};
```

It does not work. But when i try to select with `querySelector` then it only selects the first element and it works like it should. But i need it to work on both elements. Thanks in advance

edit:

my whole code

```
function menuHoverAnimation() {

        let menuSingle = document.querySelector('.navigation__single');
        let menuSingleText = document.querySelector('.navigation__single-text');

        menuSingle.onmousemove = function (e) {
            callParallax(e);
        };

        menuSingle.onmouseleave = function (e) {

            TweenMax.to(menuSingleText, 2, {
                y: 0,
                ease: Power3.easeOut
            });

        };

        function callParallax(e) {
            parallaxIt(e, menuSingleText, 500);
        }

        function parallaxIt(e, target, movement) {

            let $this = menuSingle;
            let relY = e.pageY - $this.offsetTop;

            TweenMax.to(target, 4, {
                y: (relY - $this.offsetHeight / 2) / $this.offsetHeight * movement,
                ease: Power3.easeOut
            });

        }

    }
```

demo with working example only on first child

https://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/MGOrRr

Comment: Why dont you use mouse over / mouse enter events?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you solve your problem?

Comment: @luca for now not :( i tried every single one

Comment: @Luca i added whole code, this works only for fist menuSingle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll()` returns a `HTMLElementCollection` containing the matches. You can loop through this and set the properties of each element to the desired functions:

```js
let menuSingle = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__single');
let menuSingleText = document.querySelector('.navigation__single-text');

menuSingle.forEach(elem => elem.onmouseenter = function (e) {
    callParallax(e);
});

menuSingle.forEach(elem => elem.onmouseleave = function (e) {

    TweenMax.to(menuSingleText, 2, {
        y: 0,
        ease: Power3.easeOut
    });

});
```

---

Now, that you edited your post, there are a lot more mistakes of this kind:

```js
function menuHoverAnimation() {

        let menuSingle = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__single');
        let menuSingleText = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__single-text');

        menuSingle.forEach(elem => elem.onmousemove = function (e) {
            callParallax(e);
        });

        menuSingle.forEach(elem => elem.onmouseleave = function (e) {

            TweenMax.to(menuSingleText, 2, {
                y: 0,
                ease: Power3.easeOut
            });

        });

        function callParallax(e) {
            parallaxIt(e, menuSingleText, 500);
        }

        function parallaxIt(e, target, movement) {

            let $this = menuSingle;
            let relY = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;

            TweenMax.to(e.target, 4, {
                y: (relY - e.target.offsetHeight / 2) / e.target.offsetHeight * movement, //assuming they all have the same offsetHeight
                ease: Power3.easeOut
            });

        }

    }

menuHoverAnimation();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.navigation__single {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: blue;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation__single work-screen__trigger" id="red">
  <span class="navigation__single-text">Work</span>
</div>

<div class="navigation__single about-screen__trigger">
  <span class="navigation__single-text">About</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there an error in your console about this? *How* is it not working?

Comment: I changed the first event to onmouseenter, could you try this again?

Comment: its not doing the effect on any element. no errors in console. I edited my post with whole code

Comment: Ok, there are a lot of other problems like this, I'll edit this answer to include these errors!

Comment: https://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/MGOrRr this is codepen demo with working only on first child. btw thanks for helping

Comment: Edited the function, tested with your codepen, and it seems to work (at least I think that's what you want: https://codepen.io/klequex/pen/zjPRxM )

Comment: hey Luca, really thanks for everything. No, i want effect only on the element that is hovered, now when you hover one both spans are moving

Comment: Ah, alright, give me a minute, stay on the site ;-)

Comment: Now, the background moves too, is that intended? https://codepen.io/lucakiebel/pen/zjPRxM I haven't checked out the tween library yet

Comment: I seem to have not saved the pen, now it should work, editing

Comment: See how on my demo when you hover over element only its span inside it is moving towards the mouse, and when you move away from the elemen the span goes back to its normal position. It should work like on the other element to only when its hovered. I really appreciate all your help

Comment: Please try it again, I saw my error in thinking now :)

Comment: Thats it! thank you very much, would you have the time for short explanation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `mousemove` and `mouseleave` event listener to each element with class `navigation__single`. Something like below:

```
function mousemoveFn(e){
  callParallax(e);
}

function mouseleaveFn(e){
   TweenMax.to(menuSingleText, 2, {
      y: 0,
      ease: Power3.easeOut
   });
}

let menuSingle = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__single');
for(var i=0; i<menuSingle.length; i++){
  menuSingle[i].addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveFn);
  menuSingle[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseleaveFn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Just need to loop through all the nodes to attach events to them like

```js
let menuSingle = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation__single');
let menuSingleText = document.querySelector('.navigation__single-text');


for(var i=0; i<menuSingle.length; i++){
menuSingle[i].addEventListener("onmousemove", callParallax)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Jquery, just put an ID name

```js
$( "#mydiv" ).hover(
  function() {
    console.log('Hovering');
  }, function() {
    console.log('Not Hovering');
  }
);
```

```css
#mydiv {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mydiv'>
  
</div>
```